# Retrieve all items of children root of firebase in C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How could I retrieve these subject and body with their corresponding comments dynamically in C#. show me only the way. I don't need the full program

Comment: Sow us your code? Is above pic is for json or xml? Could you please add firebase response data in text instead of image?

Comment: What if `comments` are more than one for every `body` and `subject`. Do you want only first comment per `subject`, `body` or all?

Comment: comments can be more than one. I need to retrieve all comments under their corresponding body. I have done this in android using recyclerview and arrayadapter and it is simple. but I can't succeed it in c#.

Comment: Is this a json? so could you please post it as text? So i can help you.

Comment: I sniped the picture from firebase console. I am manipulating the database directly from my C# code. I am not seeing whether it is json or xml in between. I send my request to firebase and when I got the result I set it directly to label.

Comment: Yes when you request to firebase then in response you get that result in string and then set it to label so I need this string before setting to label, got it?

Comment: Yes. but the string is the actual referenced body.

Comment: public async void loadNoti()
        {
            FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("Notification/1552681965015");
            PostData obj = response.ResultAs<PostData>();
            label_subject.Text = obj.subject;
            labelbody.Text = obj.body;
        }

Comment: internal class PostData
    {
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
    }

Comment: this is just to show you How I am accessing the body and subject

Comment: Is there any api available that call `client.GetAsync("Notification")`? without providing this number `1552681965015` so we can get all notification. then we successfully retrieve all required data

Comment: That's my question. If we can get an API to accomplish that, it is simple to complete the rest task.

Comment: yes for that you need to read proper documentation from Firebase. If its available then I'll provide you answer

Comment: as far as I read they don't have such like API that works with c#. I able to accomplish this task in android. and I have retrieved all body and subject with their comments.

Comment: Could you please show me how you `retrieved all body and subject with their comments` in android.? especially call to API. maybe I get some clue from this.

Comment: Okay, through what should I show you

Comment: download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zy6l7g21w53tcoc/here%20is%20the%20android%20classes%20and%20layout.rar?dl=1) if it is not brief tell me I will describe its classes with their specific operation.

Comment: Didn't you get something?

Comment: I didn't understand much of your code but what's this line does => `notifications=database.getReference("Notification");` in `NotificationDetail.java`.

Comment: look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dth3aq_QPzU) it does the same operation with the code I posted here. and It is the answer of my question in android.

Comment: is there any thing new?